# Eclipse error installing update Indigo 3.7.2 w/ ADK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Eclipse is running into problems with dependencies after trying to update from Indigo 3.7.1 and Android SDK 15.
It seems all the Android components installed but I get the following message "`There were no installable units selected when the plan was computed`" in the Available Updates window.

Eclipse SDK Version 3.7.2.M20120208-800 is trying to be installed.

Any help with this issue is appreciated. See more info below:

---

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse SDK 3.7.2.M20120208-0800 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.2.M20120208-0800)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1321891729401 (SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1321891729401)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Simple Configurator Manipulator 2.0.0.v20110502-1955 (org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator 2.0.0.v20110502-1955)
    Simple Configurator Manipulator 2.0.0.v20110815-1438 (org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator 2.0.0.v20110815-1438)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1321891729401 (SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1321891729401)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator [2.0.0.v20110502-1955]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.0.1.v20110906-1605-8290FZ9FVKHVRKtmx3fpNuo02129 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.v20110906-1605-8290FZ9FVKHVRKtmx3fpNuo02129)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator [2.0.0.v20110815-1438]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Provisioning for IDEs. 2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bk8pYWZz0qUTX5I15GZWwbXkrl (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bk8pYWZz0qUTX5I15GZWwbXkrl)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.0.1.v20110906-1605-8290FZ9FVKHVRKtmx3fpNuo02129]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse SDK 3.7.2.M20120208-0800 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.2.M20120208-0800)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bk8pYWZz0qUTX5I15GZWwbXkrl]
```

Answer (score 2):

Having a conflict dependency caused by "`Software currently installed:` **`Shared profile`**" is potentially a tell-tale of shared plugins issue in a [shared installation](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/epp-dev/msg01135.html) (which can't be updated unless running as administrator, as reported in [bug 339659](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339659#c15))

[Bug 322344](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322344#c3) sums it up:

> You have a number of plugins under `c:\Program Files`, and Eclipse can't write here because of UAC.  When you install add-ons (no upgrades, just extra bundles) they go in `~/.eclipse`, a hidden folder under the users home directory.
>   However, we can't perform any 'updates' in this folder because you are in a shared install mode and it's assumed the admin will 'update' the base.
>
> However, in some cases, an install will force an update (new plugin `X` depends on an update of `Y`).
>   In this case we can get into trouble, so we 'lock' the shared area so updates don't happen.
>   This is what you're hitting.

So maybe you experience some write-privilege issue when updating your Eclipse installation (as illustrated in [bug 287246](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287246#c11)).

Comment: Thanks VonC for your input.  I verified that \plugins \.eclipse folders give full control to Administrators.